# C# SocketException "No such host is known" when creating TcpServerChannel

Tags: c#, remoting, channel, socketexception

I'm currently developing a client-server-based game using C# remoting. Everything seemed to work fine until I tried to set up the `TcpServerChannel`. I'm using the complex constructor (with `IDictionary` and stuff), but the problem seems to appear even with the normal `TcpServerChannel(int port)` constructor.

A `SocketException` with the message "No such host is known" is thrown when I try to create the channel instance. Stack trace:

```
at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.GetMachineIp()
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.SetupMachineName()
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider, IAuthorizeRemotingConnection authorizeCallback)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider)
at Some.Namespace.Server.Start()
```

However, after some research I found out that the problem is the `CoreChannel.GetMachineIp()` method. I found the code of the `CoreChannel` class [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/ManagedLibraries/Remoting/Channels/CORE/CoreChannel@cs/1305376/CoreChannel@cs) and noticed, that the `Dns.GetHostEntry(string hostNameOrAddress)` method is called twice. In the first call the return value of the `Dns.GetHostName()` method (which correctly returns my computer name, lets say we got "hostname" here) is passed as argument while in the second call the returned `IPHostEntry.HostName` is passed. Here is where the problem occurs: Since my computer is inside a domain (lets call it "domain"), the returned `IPHostEntry.HostName` contains "hostname.domain" instead of just "hostname". The second `Dns.GetHostEntry("hostname.domain")` call then throws an exception because "hostname.domain" is not known.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263257/system-runtime-remoting-channels-corechannel-getmachineip-from-net-reflector), but it didn't help me in any way.

I don't know why this thing is working that way, but I can't change my computer name or the domain, so I am stuck at this point and really need some help.

I am using Windows 7 64bit (if it matters), VS Professional 2012 Update 4 and .NET Framework 4.5.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you sure you want to be building new code based on [Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.85).aspx)? " a legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development. Distributed applications should now be developed using the [Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=127777)."

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever for the quick answer. I didn't know that remoting is kind of depracted, so I guess I will learn WCF.